# Stored procedures do not see temp table created in the same connection

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

Why does my temp table get dropped?

Currently, we have:

```
var listOfSqlCommands = new List<SqlCommand>();
```

It gets populated with a `SqlCommand` with `CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Background information:

- I am creating a temp table (this creates a `SqlCommand`)
- Then take a list of stored procedures, and create a `SqlCommand` for each one
- I need to use the temp table for the other commands
- After having done a SQL Server trace, I found no indication that `sp_executesql` was being used. The profiler showed that the temp table was being created with a `exec CreateTempTableSproc`

Full code:

```
var listOfSqlCommands = new List<SqlCommand>();

using (var O0aAConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        O0aAConnection.Open();

        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
        {
            EntityName = StringDefaultIfNull(syncConfig.Root.XPathSelectElement("./entity[@name='" + dt.TableName + "']"), "O0aATableName").Substring(3);

            var O0aACommand = new SqlCommand();

            O0aACommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            O0aACommand.CommandText = "O0aA42_P_" + EntityName + "Sync_OfferingPublish";

            var entityNameParam = new SqlParameter("@EntityName", dt.TableName);

            O0aACommand.Parameters.Clear();
            O0aACommand.Parameters.Add(entityNameParam);

            var tblParam = new SqlParameter("@O42_" + EntityName, SqlDbType.Structured);
            tblParam.Value = dt;
            O0aACommand.Parameters.Add(tblParam);

            O0aACommand.Connection = O0aAConnection;

            listOfSqlCommands.Add(O0aACommand);
        }

        using (var createTempTableCommand = new SqlCommand())
        {
            createTempTableCommand.CommandText = "CreateTempTableSproc";
            createTempTableCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            createTempTableCommand.Connection = O0aAConnection;

            createTempTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        // the commands here are NOT seeing the temp table that was created above!!
        foreach (var command in listOfSqlCommands)
        {
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                da.Fill(dtResults);
            }
        }
    }                
    finally
    {
        O0aAConnection.Close();
    }            
}
```

Why does my temp table get dropped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary tables (both local and global) only exist in the context of the session OR the stored procedure in which they were created.

You have to not use a stored procedure to create it.

EXEC will also create a context for temporary tables that will go away on return from the EXEC if they are created within the EXEC.  Code called by EXEC will see existing temp tables.

Comment: how do i keep the session the same?

Comment: The session is the same if you don't do it in an SP.

Comment: use executenonquery to run the create table statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can CHAIN the results of a stored procedure

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prcCall1]
As
Begin
    Select Val=1 into #Temp
    Exec [prcCall2]
    Select * from #Temp
End

Go

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prcCall2]
As
Begin
    Update #Temp Set Val=Val+1
    --Select * from #Temp
End

Go

Exec [dbo].[prcCall1]
```

Returns

```
Val
2
```

Comment: yes this works because you are calling prcCall2 from within prcCall1.